# What type of authorization does UiPath Cloud use?

Tags: oauth, uipath, uipath-api

I am recently working with Uipath Orchestrator API and I see that they use Bearer token to authenticate. But I am confused and I do not know if this way of authentication is oAuth or it can just be called Bearer Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

So for API authentication, it depends on what orchestrator you are using.

**On-Premise**

If you are using an on-premise installation of Orchestrator you would send the following JSON body to your `Yourorchestrator.com/api/Account/Authenticate`

```
{
    "tenancyName":"default",
    "usernameOrEmailAddress":"your username",
    "password":"your password"
}
```

you will get a JSON string returned and you want to extract the value for key `result` this is your authentication token.

Now that you are authenticated you can send your requests with the following header

- Name - `Authorization`
- Value - `Bearer + your token from above`

This is your authentication done.

**Cloud**

If you are using UiPath cloud instance of orchestrator you will need to send the following JSON body

```
{
    "grant_type" : "refresh_token"
    "client_id" : "ClientId"
    "refresh_token" : "UserKey"
}
```

`ClientId` and `UserKey` are generated through the cloud instance of Orchestrator

You must also send the following header along with the JSON Body

- Name - `X-UIPATH-TenantName`
- Value - `Your tenant logical name from orchestrator`

Similar to the on-site orchestrator, this will return an authentication token, however, you will need to extract the value for key `access_token`.

To use this, you send the request with the following 2 headers

- Name - `Authorization`
- Value - `Bearer + your token from above`
- Name - `X-UIPATH-TenantName`
- Value - `Your tenant logical name from orchestrator`

There are some quite useful examples at https://postman.uipath.rocks/?version=latest

It can be quite fiddly to start with, and on-prem Orchestrator is definitely easier to connect with than Cloud orchestrator. I would definitely recommend using [Postman](https://www.postman.com) to build your API calls